# Complex integral preserve positive definitness?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\bf C\to C$ be a function defined on $\bf H$, suppose the following integral is defined:
$$\int_{\bf H} |f(z)|^2dz.$$
Does it follow that the resulting integral is not necessarily positive definite? I seem to be making a computation which seems to be so, but I'm probably making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that
\begin{align}
0\le\left|\int_{\mathbf{H}}f(z)^2\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\le\int_{\mathbf{H}}|f(z)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
always holds, which implies that the resulting integral certainly is positive definite.